# Node.js: Connect-Auth VS. EveryAuth

Tags: node.js

Can anyone give a good comparison between:
https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth
and https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth

Which seem to be the only options for [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express)/[connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)

Comment: [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) is another great express/connect auth tool; unobtrusive and lightweight, very powerful.

Comment: If you just need HTTP Basic/Digest authentication http-auth should do just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both libraries are pretty close in feature sets, especially in terms of supported providers. `connect-auth` provides support out-of-the-box to make your own oAuth providers, so that could well help you out if you’re going to need that sort of thing.

The main thing I’ve noted between the two is that I find `connect-auth` much cleaner with the way it creates and accepts the middleware; you only have to look at the amount of pre-configuration required for the middleware in `everyauth` to see that it's going to get messy.

Another thing that isn't clear is whether `everyauth` supports multiple providers at the same time; with `connect-auth`, it seems possible/more straightforward, though I’ve yet to try this myself.

Comment: to me, now seems much powerful everyauth and if you would use express it fits better, just take a look at the examples!

Answer (score 121):

I'm the author of `everyauth`.

I wrote `everyauth` because I found using `connect-auth` lacking in terms of:

1. *Easy and powerful configuration*

   To get particular, one area where it was lacking in terms of configurability was setting facebook's "scope" security settings dynamically.
2. *Good debugging support*

   I found `connect-auth` not-so-straightforward to debug in terms of pinpointing the part of the auth process was failing. This is mostly due to the way that connect-auth sets up its nested callbacks.

With everyauth, I tried to create a system that solved the issues I ran into with connect-auth.

- **On configuration** - every everyauth auth module is defined as a series of steps and configurable parameters. As a result, you have surgery-like precision over what parameters (e.g., hostname, callback url, etc.) or steps (e.g., getAccessToken, addToSession) you want altered. With `connect-auth`, if you want to change one thing besides the few built in configurable parameters each auth strategy provides, you have to re-write the entire `this.authenticate` function that defines the logic for *all* of that strategy. In other words, it has less precision of configurability than `everyauth`. In other cases, you cannot use `connect-auth`, as is -- for example, achieving dynamic facebook "scope" configurability - i.e., asking users for more facebook permissions progressively as they get to portions of your app that require more permissions.

  In addition to configurable steps and parameters, you can also take advantage of `everyauth`'s auth module inheritance. All modules inherit prototypically from the everymodule auth module. All OAuth2-based modules inherit from the oauth2 module. Let's say you want all oauth2 modules to behave differently. All you need to do is modify the oauth2 auth module, and all oauth2-based modules will inherit that new behavior from it.
- **On debugging** - `everyauth`, in my opinion, has better debugging visibility because of the very fact that it segments each module explicitly into the steps of which it is composed. By setting

  ```
  everyauth.debug = true;
  ```

  you get output of what steps in the authentication process have completed and which ones have failed. You also have granular control over how long each step in each auth strategy has before it times out.
- **On extensibility** - I designed everyauth to maximize code re-use. As mentioned before, all modules inherit prototypically from the everymodule auth module. This means that you can achieve very modular systems while at the same time having fine grained control in terms of over-riding a specific step from an ancestor module. To see how easy it is to extend everyauth with your own auth module, just take a look at any of the specific auth modules in everyauth's source.
- **On readability** - I find `everyauth` source easier to read in terms of what is going on. With `connect-auth`, I found myself jumping around the several files to understand under what contexts (i.e., during what steps, in `everyauth` parlance) each nested callback configured by a strategy was running. With `everyauth`, you know exactly what piece of logic is associated with which context (aka step). For instance, here is the code describing what happens when an oauth2 provider redirects back to your service:

  ```
  .get('callbackPath',                                                                                                                                               
       'the callback path that the 3rd party OAuth provider redirects to after an OAuth authorization result - e.g., "/auth/facebook/callback"')                     
    .step('getCode')
      .description('retrieves a verifier code from the url query')                                                                                                   
      .accepts('req res')  
      .promises('code')                                                       
      .canBreakTo('authCallbackErrorSteps')
    .step('getAccessToken')
      .accepts('code')
      .promises('accessToken extra')                                                                                                                                 
    .step('fetchOAuthUser')
      .accepts('accessToken')                                                                                                                                        
      .promises('oauthUser')
    .step('getSession')
      .accepts('req')
      .promises('session')
    .step('findOrCreateUser')                                                                                                                                        
      .accepts('session accessToken extra oauthUser')                                                                                                                
      .promises('user')
    .step('compile')
      .accepts('accessToken extra oauthUser user')
      .promises('auth')
    .step('addToSession')
      .accepts('session auth')                                                                                                                                       
      .promises(null)
    .step('sendResponse')
      .accepts('res')
      .promises(null)
  ```

  Without needing to explain how this works, its pretty straightforward to see what an oauth2 strategy does. Want to know what getCode does? The source again is very straightforward:

  ```
  .getCode( function (req, res) {
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    if (this._authCallbackDidErr(req)) {
      return this.breakTo('authCallbackErrorSteps', req, res);
    }
    return parsedUrl.query && parsedUrl.query.code;
  })
  ```

  Compare this all to `connect-auth`'s facebook code, which for me at least, took more time than I thought it should have to figure out what is getting executed when. This is mostly because of the way in which the code is spread across files and because of the use of a single `authenticate` method and nested callbacks to define authentication logic (`everyauth` uses promises to break down the logic into easily digestible steps):

  ```
  that.authenticate= function(request, response, callback) {
    //todo: makw the call timeout ....
    var parsedUrl= url.parse(request.url, true);
    var self= this;
    if( parsedUrl.query && parsedUrl.query.code  ) {
      my._oAuth.getOAuthAccessToken(parsedUrl.query && parsedUrl.query.code ,
         {redirect_uri: my._redirectUri}, function( error, access_token, refresh_token ){
           if( error ) callback(error)
           else {
             request.session["access_token"]= access_token;
             if( refresh_token ) request.session["refresh_token"]= refresh_token;
               my._oAuth.getProtectedResource("https://graph.facebook.com/me", request.session["access_token"], function (error, data, response) {
                 if( error ) {
                   self.fail(callback);
                 }else {
                   self.success(JSON.parse(data), callback)
                 }
               })
           }
      });
    }
    else {
       request.session['facebook_redirect_url']= request.url;
       var redirectUrl= my._oAuth.getAuthorizeUrl({redirect_uri : my._redirectUri, scope: my.scope })
       self.redirect(response, redirectUrl, callback);
     }
  }
  ```

**A few other differences**:

- `everyauth` supports traditional password-based authentication. `connect-auth`, as of this writing, does not.
- The foursquare and google support in connect-auth is based on the older OAuth1.a spec. `everyauth`'s foursquare and google modules are based on their implementations of the newer OAuth2 spec.
- OpenId support in `everyauth`.
- everyauth's documentation is much more comprehensive than connect-auth's.

Finally, to comment on Nathan's answer which was unsure about `everyauth` support for multiple providers at the same time, `everyauth` does support multiple, concurrent providers. The README on `everyauth`'s github page provides instructions about how to use `everyauth` to achieve this.

To conclude, I think choice of libraries depends on the developer. I, and others, find `everyauth` more powerful from their point of view. As Nathan's answer illustrates, yet others find `connect-auth` more tuned in to their preferences. Whatever your choice, I hope this write-up about why I wrote `everyauth` helps you in your decision.

Comment: Thanks mate. Very informational and great that a developer cares enough not only about all the things you mentioned, but also about hustling it. Props to you :)

Comment: This was very useful. Thanks for the super detailed explanation. The debugging features definitely sold me.

Comment: @Brian, I'm trying to create a Facebook Canvas app and I want to use everyauth, how do I use everyauth in this situation ?

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd mention that there is now a new player in the town called [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) which features a lot of the same benefits as everyauth however authentication providers are provided by npm modules - so optin in rather than include everything.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a morning playing with everyauth and mongoose-auth to find the examples were broke and they were dead projects.  Here are the commit histories:

https:// github.com/jaredhanson/passport/commits/master - June 5th (it's June 18th)
https:// github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/commits/master - April 18th (2 months ago)
https:// github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/commits/master  - Feb 2012

Here's a google Trends of everyauth, connect-auth, and passportjs
http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=passportjs%2C+connect-auth%2C+everyauth#q=passportjs%2C%20connect-auth%2C%20everyauth&cmpt=q

Answer (score 0):

My experience with each:

`everyauth` is *far* more configurable.  For example, I wish to handle my own sessions.  With `everyauth`, with its modularity and introspection, a straightforward task.  On the other hand have found everyauth filled with minor bugs and incomplete and/or incorrect documentation.  For me, each authentication strategy has required its own understanding and troubleshooting.

`passport` might be a good bet if you're doing everything "by the book".  But any deviation could make life very difficult very quickly, making it, for *me*, a non-starter.