# authenticate user with mongoose + express.js

Tags: express, mongoose

What's the best way to authenticate a user with Mongoose and ExpreeJS.

I'm using mongoose 3.x and it looks like this package isn't being updated anymore: https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth

Ideally I could authenticate user with twitter and facebook too.

Answer (score 10):

I always prefer not to use a plugin or module for every problem. Using just mongoose you could do it like this:

Have a db.js for your mongoDB configuration

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://...");
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  salt: String,
  hash: String
});
exports.User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

Use TJ's [pass.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/pass.js) file to hash passwords. It uses [crypto.pbkdf2](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_callback) for encryption.

Create a user by hand or use a form to allow self registration:

```
var db = require('./db');
var pwd = require('./pwd');
var user = new db.User();
user.username = "Admin";
pwd.hash("adminPassword", function(err, salt, hash) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  user.salt = salt;
  user.hash = hash;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("user saved");
    }
  });
});
```

Now you should have a user with username, encrypted password and hash in your db. To check on login use a middleware function:

```
function authenticate(name, pass, fn) {
  db.User.findOne ({username: name}, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) return fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
    hash(pass, user.salt, function(err, hash){
      if (err) return fn(err);
      if (hash == user.hash) return fn(null, user);
      fn(new Error('invalid password'));
    })
  })
}

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (user) {
      req.session.regenerate(function(){
        req.session.user = user;
        res.redirect('back');
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect('login');
    }
  });
});

// middleware
function restrict(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    req.session.error = 'Access denied!';
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

// route with restrict middleware
app.get('/restricted', restrict, function(req, res){
  res.send('Wahoo! restricted area');
});
```

Most of the code is taken from the [auth](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/auth) example and I added the stuff for mongoose. Hope this helps!

Comment: That was quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I used this example when learning how to do this with MongoDB and Node:

https://github.com/braitsch/node-login

I think it is a really good isolated example of doing user authentication yourself. It uses bcrypt to hash and salt user passwords. and if you look inside [AccountManager](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login/blob/master/app/server/modules/account-manager.js) you can see how it works with the Mongo database.

However, if you wish to authenticate using other strategies I suggest you check out [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/). I haven't had a chance to use it, but I think it looks pretty well developed and simple enough. Perhaps you can update this page with your experience with it.

Comment: thanks. i was looking at Passport, but I don't think it's flexible enough, I couldn't see a way to customize how users are authenticated. I will peak through node-login code, and cringe at the jade :)

Comment: I cringed at the Jade as well. I am an [EJS](embeddedjs.com) guy myself. Regardless of what templating (if any) you use, you should be able to use node-login as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

[Everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) is another option, especially if you're looking for lots of flexibility and support for authenticating via third parties like twitter and facebook.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197767/1259510) from the author in another SO question for a good overview of its features and benefits.