# Connect-Auth vs Everyauth vs Passport vs Authom - for realtime web apps?

Tags: node.js, authorization, passport.js, everyauth, socketstream

What are some of the positive and negative comparisons between these for develop realtime web apps? I use `SocketStream` now.

Comment: This question is vague. What are you asking, exactly? Try to be more specific, and you will get a better answer. Are there specific metrics you are concerned about? (E.g., performance, features, support?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: You might refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498005/user-authentication-libraries-for-node-js

Comment: I was using `everyauth` and switched to `passport`

Comment: also a quick answer of the first two http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765063/node-js-connect-auth-vs-everyauth

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation on integrating SocketStream with EveryAuth here: https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream/blob/master/doc/guide/en/authentication.md

There is also a tutorial here (in Japanese): [http://new.takyam.com/entry/2013/01/01/SocketStreamにeveryauthでTwitterログインさせる](http://new.takyam.com/entry/2013/01/01/SocketStream%E3%81%ABeveryauth%E3%81%A7Twitter%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)

A couple of months ago, I did attempt to integrate passport-js into SocketStream, but I need to do some more work on that, and that will take time. I will let you know how I progress.